# C++ Save console output to a text file before quit WINAPI ( No MFC )

Tags: c++, winapi, file-io, console

I am trying to get my program to log the output of a console application to a text file before it quits. This is a GUI program which launches the console application (tool.exe). The problem is that I am using CTRL + C to quit the console application. This console application cant be altered either. I have tried a few ways of doing this but none have seemed to work ( tool.exe > output.txt ).

Can anyone point me in the right direction of which approach to take ? It would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The file is created but it is empty and does not receive any data. The thing I am after noticing though is if I run the tool from the command line myself, it will work. Eg. `c:\>tool.exe > output.txt` However this is not working when its executed from my GUI application.

Here is the code I am using to execute the tool:

```
    strcpy (tool, "\" start /D \"");
    strcat (tool, toolLocation);
    strcat (tool, "\" tool.exe > output.txt\"");
    system (tool);
```

This will run tool.exe and create output.txt fine but will not output anything to the file.

**EDIT2:**

I think what is actually happening is that because I am using `start` , the `>output.txt` is outputing `start` instead of `tool.exe`. This would explain why it creates the empty file. Start is just running a fresh command line which is then running `tool.exe`. The problem is, how do I get around this issue now ?

Comment: I've just tried ``ping stackoverflow.com /t > test.txt``, ended it with Ctrl-C and it worked as it should.

Comment: @Agent_L `ping` handles the interrupt signal and outputs the final results before exiting.

Comment: @Drise The file is updated on the go, long before signal is raised.

Comment: What other ways have you tried?  Have you tried using `CreateProcess` and supplying appropriate handles for `STARTUPINFO::hStdOutput` and `STARTUPINFO::hStdError`?  If you do it that way, I'd expect that you could disable buffering or explicitly flush if you need to. (The source code to my silentbatch program http://www.taenarum.com/software/silentbatch.zip might help.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code which managed to solve the problem for me:

```
            char path[500]; //Create character array
            strcpy (path, "cd "); //Copy 'cd' into the array
            strcat (path, toolLocation); //Copy the path of the tool into the array
            strcat (path, " & ip.exe > output.txt"); //Append on the name of the exe and output to a file
            system (path); //Run the built array
```

I am creating a character array and then appending to it. The vital bit here was the `&` being used in the system call. This is working as an `and` and first cd'ing to the firectory before executing the .exe.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#include <signal.h>
void signal_handlerkill(int sig)
{
  //Do Soemthing
  exit(1);
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGINT, signal_handlerkill); //Connect the interrupt signal (^C) to the function
  //Do your code here
  return 0;
}
```

And if that doesn't work, I'd suggest looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Specifically:

```
// crt_signal.c
// compile with: /c
// Use signal to attach a signal handler to the abort routine
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void SignalHandler(int signal)
{
    printf("Application aborting...\n");
}

int main()
{
    typedef void (*SignalHandlerPointer)(int);

    SignalHandlerPointer previousHandler;
    previousHandler = signal(SIGABRT, SignalHandler);

    abort();
}
```

Comment: The windows variant is `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` See [MSDN CTRL+C and CTRL+BREAK Signals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: You know... I just noticed that the excerpt I just posted is practically doing exactly what I already suggested... Oh well.

Comment: This would be useful IF he could modify the program.

Comment: @Agent_L Why wouldn't he be able to modify it?

Comment: @Drise "This console application cant be altered either". His words.

Comment: @Agent_L .. I missed that. My bad.

Comment: Yes that would more than likely work for me, but I cant touch the code of the console application.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the application without redirecting to a file, do you see the output you need on the console when you press ctrl+c?

If you don't then there is nothing you can do since you cannot change the application.

**Update**

What you need is to redirect stdout and stderr to the file. I have never done that but jamesdlin seems to have done that. Take a look at his comment.

What you could try is instead of using `start` try using `cmd.exe` directly.

Comment: The tool runs continuously, CTRL + C is the only way to quit it bar closing the console window ( Much like Airodump in backtrack ). While its running its spitting out network data to the console. This is what I am trying to log in a file.

Comment: That i think is understood. Does this part that you normally see in the console, not available in the file? Does nothing appear in the file or just the last few lines you were expecting?

Comment: I have updated my original question in response to your comment.

Comment: Hehe this new information absolutely changes the whole context of the question... I think not only I but everyone was assuming you were running it from the console directly.

Comment: Re reading my question I can now see my brain lapse in not including that Its running from a GUI app, D'oh! Ill fix that now. Sorry for the confusion.